# Bug with ScientificForm[] and Around[]?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, around

I'm using Mathematica 12.3.

You can use `ScientificForm[]` to display a number using scientific notation irregardless of its magnitude. When using `Around[]` this behaviour seems broken. For example:

```
ScientificForm[0.01]
>> 1.*10^(-2)

ScientificForm@Around[{.01, .02}]
>> 0.015±0.007
```

The `Around` still displays in scientific form when numbers are small enough for the default scientific notation to kick in.

```
Around[{.000001, .000002}]
>> (1.5±0.7)*10^(-6)
```

Is there a way to still get this working? Is this is a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various `*Form` functions are wrappers that trigger special display functionality. They are targeted to particular types of expressions. For example, TableForm is intended to be used with List-headed expressions, and it won't have any visible effect on other expressions (although it will still be there as a wrapper).

My guess here is that no display functionality has been implemented for ScientificForm when applied to Around expressions.

You could force the issue:

```
MapAt[ScientificForm, Around[{.01, .02}], 1]
```

I don't know what the consequences of that will be if you try to use that modified Around expression in further computations.

In addition, the documentation labels Around as Experimental, so I don't think it's appropriate to report this as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and workaround! Note for those who want to use this workaround:  it only applies scientific form to the value, not the uncertainty. So it produces slightly different results than expected.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that's what would be wanted. You could also just map ScientificForm to everything: `ScientificForm /@ Around[{.01, .02}]`.

Comment: Ideally I would want it to look like `(1.5±0.7)*10^(-6)` but it's okay I will just have to do it a little more manually

Comment: You could define your own bespoke display function.